# PHP code before doctype in xsl

Tags: php, xslt

I am using XSL to transform an XML document.  Is there a way to build the template with PHP code before the `<!doctype html>` declaration?

```
<!-- I want some PHP code to go here -->
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
error_reporting(0);
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])));
require_once(__ROOT__."/classes/CasController.class.php");
$cas = new CasController();
?</xsl:processing-instruction>
<!-- XSL content goes after here -->
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <!-- begin html -->
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body> 
    </html> 
    <!-- end html -->
</xsl:template>
```

ouput HTML would be

```
<?php error_reporting(0);
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])));
require_once(__ROOT__."/classes/Controller.class.php");?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The error I am getting is: Element xsl:processing-instruction must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

To include PHP before the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, use `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no" />` without the `version="5.0"` attribute.  This will declare the output as HTML without the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Insert your PHP processing instruction where you want it to go in your template:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])));
?</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Then create the doctype tag by using XML output escaping:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
```